# How to keep image aspect ratio inside resizable div?

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a resizable div like this:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fxnwzv7/)

```css
#img_wrapper{
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:gray;
  height:15rem;
  width:15rem;
  
  min-height:15rem;
  min-width:15rem;
  user-select:none;
  
}

#img_testing{
    display:block;
    
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    
    width:70%;

}
```

```html
<div id="img_wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zJvjmKs/icon.png" id="img_testing">
</div>
```

I'm trying to keep the aspect ratio of the image to whichever size the div is resized

for example:

This is correct
[image]

This is incorrect
[image]

Whereas it should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use max height and width values, then force the proportions of the image using the object-fit attribute

```css
#img_wrapper {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
  min-height: 15rem;
  min-width: 15rem;
  user-select: none;
}

#img_testing {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zJvjmKs/icon.png" id="img_testing">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! but a [small problem](https://jsfiddle.net/zb250ygc/1/): if I add `border-radius` and then expand horizontally, the border radius goes away

Comment: @cakelover Interesting! I'll have to take a look at it when I get a chance but I think you're going to have to get the border-radius attribute to do some math or use a variable to keep it from completely disappearing.

Comment: @cakelover https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/uvom5sb6/ it looks like if you set the width and height of the image to auto it'll allow the border-radius to remain as set. I couldn't tell you why the explicit value throws it off but it looks like the overall code still does what you originally wanted and you get the border raidus

Comment: that does work in keeping the border radius, However it no longer makes the image always have the same 70% width as resizable div which kind of defeats the purpose of having a resizable div :/

Comment: @cakelover I'm not seeing a difference with or without the 70% width though. You're already telling the image it's not able to be any larger than 70% of the container it's in and the container itself has min-width and min-height attributes so it can't be any smaller than that either. Looking at it in the inspector, it doesn't look like the browser is calculating it any differently between having auto or 70%, it's just not breaking the border radius with the auto values in place.